# How to get localized month name without declension

Tags: python

I want to get localized month name without applied declension. For example in polish `July` is `lipiec` but to `12th of July` is spelled `12 lipca`. The code below outputs `lipca` on my system.

```
import calendar
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')    
month = calendar.month_name[datetime.datetime.now().month]
print(month)
```

Comment: Python's `calendar` module relies on the C runtime library's `locale` functions.  If the C library doesn't know how to do it, then Python won't, either.  You may just need to hardcode an array of 12 strings.

Comment: Interestingly, I got `lipiec` on my system. Python 3.11.1  Default locale is `en-US`. `import locale, calendar`; `locale.setlocale(0, 'polish')`; `calendar.month_name[1:]` outputs: 
`['styczeń', 'luty', 'marzec', 'kwiecień', 'maj', 'czerwiec', 'lipiec', 'sierpień', 'wrzesień', 'październik', 'listopad', 'grudzień']`

Comment: I should have added I'm also on Windows 10, which may make a difference if you're in some other OS.